# Construct ellipse from five points in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, plugin

It is known that we could construct an ellipse (or any other conic section) [using five points](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1217797/57054). I've found a [plugin for Inkscape](http://pernsteiner.org/inkscape/ellipse_5pts/) that do that construction. But I want to solve this task in Illustrator.

Is there any plugin for Adobe Illustrator that could construct an ellipse using five points?

Comment: Not that i know of. But i do have a script that does this somewhere on my hard disk. Would that be an acceptable solution. Its not that i couldnt make a plugin of it but I'd rather not as its a bit painfull to setup a compiling environment that checks and tests cross platform compiles.

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes, there is a script.

The script is called [`Circle.jsx`](https://github.com/shspage/illustrator-scripts/tree/master/etc#ovalizejsx) by *Hiroyuki Sato*

You can run the script and then just choose how many anchors you want your circle to have.

---

`Ovalize.jsx` is the **new version** of `Circle.jsx` which didn't perform the extra stuff which Ovalize does, it only created a circle by custom amount of points (**which is what you want**).

If you wanted to use Ovalize, you'd have to create a path first. (You can make an ellipse and then run the script and select the amount of points and it will adjust.)

You can still download `Circle.jsx` from [their website](http://shspage.com/aijs/en/#circle).

> The old version of [Ovalize](http://shspage.com/aijs/en/#ovalize).
> This script draws a circle that has specified number of anchor points at the center of the active artboard.

Just download the zip file which has lots of other useful scripts as well, `Circle.jsx` will be in the folder `\\doc\legacy_and_extra\`

---

If you **always** want to have 5 point ellipses and save a couple seconds by skipping the prompt, you can modify the line in the script from

```
number_of_anchors = prompt("number of anchors", number_of_anchors);
```

to

```
number_of_anchors = 5;
```

and then save the script as something like `5ptEllipse.jsx`.

Comment: OP is not asking for a circle with 5 points, but rather what conic passes the arbitrary 5 points user defines.

Comment: Indeed, the script does not work like the Inkscape script.

Comment: The script does not draw an ellipse that pass through the given five points.